# EditTextPreference keep last value as hint

Tags: android, edittextpreference

I've got this edit text preference

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:title="@string/settings_server"
        android:summary="@string/server_name_message"
        android:key="SERVER_NAME" />
```

It keeps the last value added. How I can delete the hint from it?

Comment: That's the nature of an EditTextPreference - it stores the value the user enters into it.  Do you just want an EditText perhaps?

Comment: But the problems is that it don't show the value saved in preference, it shows the last value insert in the edit text box.

Comment: Are you saying that you enter a value into the EditTextPreference, THEN change the preference value from code somewhere else, THEN come back to the EditTextPreference, and it has reverted to its original value?

Comment: I try to explain my use case. I' ve got the "server name" preference. If i logout from the app i clear all the preference. When I go to settings if I click on the edittextpreference the hint is the last I put (but there is no value saved in preference)

Comment: Do it in code of course

Answer (score 0):

You can load the preference for an `EditTextPreference` from an Xml file by creating a sub class of `PreferenceActivity` and setting the Preference of that element using 
      `addPreferencesFromResource();`